# Calling a method from outside a class in Java

Tags: java, instance-methods, arrays, class-method

This seems to be a common question on here but for all the ones I read, they seem to deal with different things.

I'm writing a program with a main class that manages an array of objects of a different class, and I'm having difficulty calling a print() method from this second class, from within the main class.

The Main class attempts to call print(), which is in the Unit class. The Unit class looks something like this:

```
public class Unit{

    static int numOfUnits = 0;
    public Unit[] units = new Unit[8];

    private int unitID;

//constructors are here

    public void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < units.length; i++)
    System.out.print(units[i].unitID);
    }

    public void add(Unit unit){
    mobs[numbofUnits] = unit;
    numOfUnits++;
    }
}
```

So what I'd like to happen is, through the Main class, I add new Unit objects to the units array. When I'm done adding them (using the call unitToAdd.add(unitToAdd) in the Main class) I would like to call Unit's print() method from within Main.

What I don't know is, whether or not, and where, to use the static modifier, how to refer to the variables in the print() method itself (that is, do I use this.unitID, units[i].unitID, etc) and so on.

What is confusing me is simply the nature of the print() method. I have setters and getters that work just fine since I completely understand that calling specificUnit.setID() is changing a specific variable for that specific object, but I don't know how to get methods like print() to work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post the code from your Main class

Comment: do you really want Unit to have an array of Units? seems like you could be confused on how to group things into classes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - you need a `Unit` instance to invoke `print()`. I *strongly* recommend that you go back to the basics - [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: agreed - there is some major design confusion on the whole here

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid implementing a list of `Unit`s in `Unit`.  You can avoid static state altogether by creating a `UnitList` class to store your list of units, maybe in an `ArrayList`, and then creating a `UnitList` instance that is local to your `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
  UnitList myUnitList = new UnitList();
  myUnitList.add(new Unit(...));
  myUnitList.print();
}
```

That separates out the concern of tracking a set of units from the units themselves and avoids global mutable state which is hard to debug and unit test.

To answer your question though, below is the minimal set of changes with some explanation as to why they should be `static` or not.

```
public class Unit{

  // static here since every unit does not need to have a number of units.
  static int numOfUnits = 0;
  // static here since every unit does not need to contain other units.
  static Unit[] units = new Unit[8];

  // no static here since every unit does need its own ID.
  private int unitID;

  //constructors are here

  // static here since every unit does not need to know how 
  // to print a particular 8 units.
  public static void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfUnits; i++)
      System.out.print(units[i].unitID);
  }

  // static here since every unit does not need to know how
  // to add to a global list.
  public static void add(Unit unit){
    mobs[numbofUnits] = unit;
    numOfUnits++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider what will happen if you want to have more than one Units.

Comment: The "list" is still shared by all instances of Units.

Comment: @Thorbjørn, how so?  If the list is stored in a `UnitList` instance, then it is entirely separable from `Unit` and involves no mutable static state.

Comment: @Thorbjørn, yes, I clearly call out problems with static mutable state, and explain how to fix them.  With that caveat in mind, I then make the minimal changes to demonstrate when and where `static` should appear to answer the limited question the OP actually asked.  If it isn't clear to you now that I've taken into account what happens when "you want to have more than one Units[sic]" then I don't think further discussion is worthwhile.